# Is there a problem with Roblox Studio or my script?

Tags: lua, roblox

The script is not working. The camera is still controlled by the player.

I tried

```
local camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    
    while true do
        camera.CFrame = CFrame.new(humanoid.RootPart.Position, humanoid.RootPart.Position + Vector3.new(2, 0.36, 0))
        wait()
    end
end)
```

but it did not work.
I wanted the camera to stay in the direction 2, 0.36, 0 and just not be able to be adjusted by the player.

Comment: Consider changing the [CameraType](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/enums/CameraType) to `Enum.CameraType.Attach`.